# How can I stop mail DNS records from showing my main website?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, dovecot, lamp

I’m relatively new to all this, so please bear with me. Most of everything I know is based on guesswork, following tutorials, trial & error…

Anyway, I have a pretty basic LAMP server going on Ubuntu Server 20.04, with some other stuff like WordPress, Postfix, Dovecot, etc. At the moment, everything functions as it should, but I did not realise my DNS MX records display my website in your browser (I found this out by mistake). As in if you put “mail.example.com” into a browser, it comes up with my WordPress site.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? I have my DNS records setup as normal, with A records, MX, etc. I’m not sure if this is typically normal or not for your MX record to show your main website.

Thanks!

Comment: Why even care *care*? Worst that could happen is that someone trying to figure out why your mail server is spamming them, finds your WordPress site with your contact info.. which may still be more useful than what you propose: stopping that to show as the default.

Comment: I just didn’t necessarily want that to happen, and especially since when you do it, it takes you to an insecure version of the site when it’s supposed to have an SSL cert with LetsEncrypt.